# .NET MAUI Maps Zoom Event

Tags: .net, google-maps, maui

I need to be able to listen to a Map Zoom Event. On Android (I assume AppleMaps is the same) only allows for plotting 10 pins at once. When a user zooms out I need to be able to perform action loading more pinpoints, but I don't see any event that ties to the zoom (aside from MapPropertyChanged, which is called when loaded, plotted, etc can't use it).

Is there an event that I'm missing that captures zoom? Perhaps one that passes the Zoom in the EventArgs when changed?

Comment: Looking at docs, I also don't see any event that fires when user zooms. A possible work-around is to have a timer that reads Map.VisibleRegion every second (or as desired). Keep track of previous region value; compare to value read; if it changes, then you know its either a pan or a zoom. Can calculate zoom from region size. If you decide to implement this, then when you get it working, add Your Answer below to show the actual code.